# How can I make my database accessible from another system?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, windows, mysql-workbench, pymysql

I am using mysql 8.0 server. I have created database in my system. Now, I want to access that database from another system. while making connection from another system it throws error : Access denied .

how to solve this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL MariaDB Server Raspberry Pi remote access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564439/mysql-mariadb-server-raspberry-pi-remote-access)

Comment: How to change the bind address, because in windows there isn't my.cnf file. And also if I type "create user 'user'@'%' identified by 'password';. It throws error saying operation create user failed

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have experience with windows. It seems the installation places configuration files in other places. Also, the Windows security infrastructure may be placing some restrictions in the user creation. I added the "windows" tag to your question to point it in the right direction. In my very personal opinion, I would suggest you set up MySQL in a linux server, since it's much easier (not trying to evangelize, it's just very straighforward).